# Show and hide UIImageView in tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

What is the best way to show and hide `UIImageView` on `UIButton` click in `UITableViewCell` (custom class).

Actually my row height it's calculated with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and I've set up all necessary constraint.

**ISSUE**: It's better change the cell height or the `UIImageView` height?

If I change the height constraint of my `UIImageView` until the cell is reloaded the height doesn't change.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: if we change your imageView's height then cell height should be affected or not ?

Comment: No until reloadData() isn't called

Comment: Can u please provide your tableviewcell screenshot ? so we can understand that what you want ?

Comment: I think that is already clear

Comment: @vikasprajapati she have `UIImageView` and `UIButton` in custom prototype cell. Now she wanted to hide `UIImageView` on `UIButton` click. Height of row is according to the visible content in prototype cell.

Comment: @Mala Never take the outlet of constraints until unless it is not necessary, because it is not a good coding practice.

Comment: You should install and uninstall (active/inactive) the `UIImageView` Constraint and you should do a `layoutIfNeeded` on the cell it self, so that it changes it's height to adjust to the constraint changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let you have custom class of `UITableViewCell` says, `CustomTableCell`. In `CustomTableCell` you take the outlet of `UIImageView` (says, imageView). take action of your `UIButton` (says, btnShow).

**Implement below methods;**

First take a global array in your VC, says arrSelected

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
          return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let customCell : CustomTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableCell

        customCell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
        customCell.btnShow.tag = indexPath.row;

     var xPos : CGFloat!
     var yPos : CGFloat!
     var width : CGFloat!
     var height : CGFloat!

    xPos = cell.imageView.frame.origin.x
    width = cell.imageView.frame.size.width
    height = cell.imageView.frame.size.height

    if  arrSelected.contains(indexPath.row) { 
        yPos = 100 // whatever the height of imageview when image is present
    cell.imageView.isHidden = false

    }
    else{
     yPos = cell.btnShow.frame.size.height 
     cell.imageView.isHidden = true
    }

        cell.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: width, height: height)         

        return customCell
    }

    // btnShow action

    @IBAction func actionbtnShow(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected {
         let itemToRemoveIndex = arrSelected.indexOf(sender.tag) {
    arrSelected.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    }
    else{
         arrSelected.append(sender.Tag)
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    }

    // reload tableView
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could set the hidden tag in an animated block and pack the beginUpdates and endUpdates of the tableView in the same block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations:{
    imageView.isHidden = false
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
})
```

Alternatively in Objective-C:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    imageView.hidden = NO;
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}];
```

Like this, the height of the cell should grow animated.

Comment: This is not Swift

Comment: This not the answer of her question, she is not asking about animation.